# action="mailto:*email address*" in form not working over HTTPS

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, https, mailto

I want to create a simple contact page for my website. I created a form like this (using React).

```
<Form
   action="mailto:btrorapps@gmail.com"
   method="post"
   encType="text/plain"
   autocomplete="off"
>
```

It's got some Form controls to gather data and a submit button.

Works perfectly fine when I run it on localhost. When I update the code for my website that uses HTTPS I get this weird autofill error.
[image]

If I ignore all that and type a message anyway and submit, I get this.

[image]

How can I fix both of these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The connection to the HTTPS site is secure. The `mailto:` URL (which goes to plain text email) is not. The browser warns the user that the "This is a secure site!" icon in their toolbar will not apply if they carry on.

You can't stop the browser warning the user when it detects your site is leaving security behind.

`mailto:` as a form action is [highly unreliable](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) (I would never use it on the WWW) which is another reason not to go down this route. Use a server side form processor instead (and send the data to it with HTTPS).

Comment: Like nodejs or php? I'm new to this stuff and don't want to pay to keep a script running.